When the HTTP message body is not received in full at one time, how does Nginx handle the remaining parts that are about to arrive?
Recently,i'm reading nginx1.16 source code about how http module handle http body. In the case that http body is not received in full at one time, and remain http body content comes later.
if data is about fastcgi, Body handler will be insert to CONTET_PHASE, based on https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/branches/stable-1.16/src/http/modules/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.c#L3513
Assume that:
1. buffers in ngx_http_request_t is enough（no need to alloc another buffer memory）

2. Transfer-Encoding is not chunked.

3. content_length is 100 bytes. only recve 50 byts 1st, another 50 byts comes later.

4. http body content is about fastcgi, so ngx_http_fastcgi_handler will be insert to CONTENT_PHASE.

let's browse related code, maybe not correct,

https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/branches/stable-1.16/src/http/ngx_http_request_body.c#L100
after ngx_http_request_bdoy_filter, there is a new ngx_chain_t mounted on ngx_http_request r->request_body->bufs.

https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/branches/stable-1.16/src/http/ngx_http_request_body.c#L128
do not receive complete http body, so will go into this if branch. before execute do_read_client_request_body,the action read_event_handler will be set to ngx_http_read_client_request_body_handler. this action will be tirggered in ngx_http_request_handler which be callbacked after epoll_wait.

https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/branches/stable-1.16/src/http/ngx_http_request_body.c#L336
read buffer in socket kernal buffer, if there in not package in kernal socket buffer code will break the loop, and then go to
https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/branches/stable-1.16/src/http/ngx_http_request_body.c#L387
because all packages has been recived in ngx_unix_recv, so c->read_ready flag will be reset to false.and the value of request_body_no_buffering is 0. so code will directly goto
https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/branches/stable-1.16/src/http/ngx_http_request_body.c#L407
add client_body_timeout timer event, and register the c->read event(callback function is ngx_http_request_handler, but actually event action is ngx_http_read_client_request_body_handler, because read_event_handler will be executed in ngx_http_request_handler).
Then return NGX_AGAIN.

code will go from https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/branches/stable-1.16/src/http/ngx_http_request_body.c#L133 to
https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/branches/stable-1.16/src/http/ngx_http_request_body.c#L208
and then go back to https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/branches/stable-1.16/src/http/modules/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.c#L754
Then return value chagne to NGX_DONE

code will go back to https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/branches/stable-1.16/src/http/ngx_http_core_module.c#L1169

in ngx_http_finalize_request function, code will go to https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/branches/stable-1.16/src/http/ngx_http_request.c#L2426
then goto https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/branches/stable-1.16/src/http/ngx_http_request.c#L2720

then jump to https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/branches/stable-1.16/src/http/ngx_http_request.c#L2992
in the function of ngx_http_set_keepalive, anyway, will jump to ngx_http_free_request(r, 0);
then the memory pool will be clean up.
https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/branches/stable-1.16/src/http/ngx_http_request.c#L3654
so what make me feel confuse is that how to handle the remain 50byes which comes later after the request memory pool was clean up?
In step 1, the mount ngx_chain_t which saved 1st 50 bytes will be deleted too. i think all the relative meomry comes memory pool. so the previous 50bytes discard?



I miss the key points: the valid http request totally rely on the r->main->count. The initial value of this count is 1 when http request was allocated in the ngx_http_alloc_request function. when the body handled by the function of ngx_http_read_client_request_body, r->main->count++ to 2. so the connection will kept. the ngx_http_close_request function will return directly with doing nothing.
